# Custom label inside if not working

Tags: visualforce, customlabel

I have used custom label inside if in vf page its not working....

```
<label>{!IF(ISNULL(cases.Account.mobile), '{!$Label.Rf_Label_No}', cases.Account.mobile)}</label><br></br>
```

> Getting same as Output:#{$Label.Rf_Label_No}

Comment: Try using ISBLANK in place of ISNULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<label>{!IF(ISNULL(cases.Account.mobile), $Label.Rf_Label_No, cases.Account.mobile)}</label><br></br>
```

'' has to be used with when you want to print a string.
{} has to be used when you start a code.
If your case you are already inside a code block. So you need not to add {} or ''

Comment: Your answer would be greater if you'd also explain it ..

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke does that means you'll give -1

Comment: Much more likely  he's explaining why someone else did so.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for your feedback guys. I thought it would be much better if one figure it out themselves. This was vary basic.

Comment: Looking at two long strings and trying to spot the difference isn't a very good way to learn.

Comment: @ShankerPaudel yes that is why I downvoted your answer, and have now upvoted it in consideration of your update.